# SQL table referring to a subset of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a table, with some Materials: gold, water, ice.
Each material can be either: solid, liquid.

I want to add a new table, called Shape, which obviously would contain information only for solid materials (liquids do not possess a definite shape).

I came to the conclusion to add this table, and fill it with NULL values for liquid.

But is there a cleaner solution? (a Shape table whose rows would just refer to solids).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your issue.  You would simply add:

```
create table shapes (
    shape_id int auto_increment primary key,
    material_id int,
    . . . 
    foreign key (material_id) references materials (material_id)
);
```

You would only add rows in `shapes` for solids, because it doesn't (generally) apply to other types of solids.  This data model does not enforce that constraint.  That is possible, but I don't know if enforcing it is necessary.  As for your example, there is meaningful debate on whether glass is a liquid or solid.